# ¿Cómo mostrar lo valores de una consulta en un select creado desde una funcion Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
//Obtengo los resultados de la consulta en `PHP` por `AJAX`:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "consulta.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false
}).done(function(echo){
  $("#rs").html(echo);
});
});
```

Creo la función que creará un campo `select` en una tabla

```
function crearCampoSelect(nombre){
 td = document.createElement('td');
 sel = document.createElement('select');
 sel.setAttribute('name',nombre);
 sel.setAttribute('id','rs'); 
 td.appendChild(sel);
 return td;
};
</script>
```

El campo `select` se crea pero, no muestra el mensaje que si me llega en la consulta. el problema lo tengo en la función `crearCampoSelect()` porque en el `html` creo la etiqueta `<select id='rs'>` y me muestra el echo de la consulta que es:

```
mensaje = '<option value='.$nombre.'>'.$nombre.'</option>';
echo $mensaje;
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal en la función? Qué me sugieren para arreglarlo?

Comment: Necesitarías mandar llamar la función `crearCampo` antes de poder hacer tu llamado ajax, de lo contrario no encontrará el select que estás buscando. ¿De qué manera y en qué momento mandas llamar tu función `crearCampoSelect` ?

Comment: lo mando llamar mediante <button type='button' onclick='crearCampoSelect();'>

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es en tu función al terminar la creación del elemento manda llamar tu ajax, esto creando una nueva función donde esté tu llamado y puedas entonces así obtener tus opciones y agregarla al elemento que acabas de crear.

Comment: Aquí hay una coma (,) que te está comiendo: `td,appendChild(sel);`reemplaza por `td.appendChild(sel);` ¿No?

Comment: gracias por tu aportacion Lixus pero no funciona, gracias por tu aportacion A.Cedano pero esa coma fué error mio al escribir el codigo

Comment: Evidentemente el código no viene de un cortar y pegar ya que faltan comillas, paréntesis, etc., es importante que muestres el código tal cual lo estas usando, no es que esto sea importante para ayudarte pero lo pones a pensar que mas podrá estar faltando?.. ejemplo en la instrucción **ajax** te falta un paréntesis `.ajax({`, en la llamada (#rs) te faltan las comillas `("#rs")`, corrigelos y nos cuentas como va, Saludos!!... ;))

Comment: gracias por tu observacion fwBasic, ya corregi los errores de sintaxix en el ejemplo, el ajax no es el problema, como lo comento en la pregunta, si creo un select en el html con el id="rs", me pone los valores de la consulta, lo que no se es, como lo integro a mi funcion crearCampoSelect() para que al ser creado el campo select tambien me muestre los datos de la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya vi donde estaba mi error y ya lo corregí, agradezco los cometarios de todos los que me apoyaron, aquí les dejo la solución. slds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Detalle</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>
  function crearCampoSelect(){
   var destino = document.createElementById('tbAgregar');
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   var sel = document.createElement('select');
   sel.setAttribute('id','rs');
   td.appendChild(sel);
   tr.appendChild(td);
   destino.appendChild(tr);
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'consulta.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          cache: false,
          contentType: false
        }).done(function(echo){
          $('rs').html(echo);
        });
     });
  };
 </script>
 <div>
 <button type="button" onclick="crearCampoSelect();">Agregar</button>
 </div>
 <div>
 <table width="100" border="1">
  <thead>Nombres</thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Usuarios</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tbAgregar">
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </body>  
</html>
```

mi consulta.php me manda lo siguiente:

```
$mensaje = '<option value=Nombre1>Nombre1</option><option value=Nombre2>Nombre2</option><option value=Nombre3>Nombre3</option>';
echo $mensaje;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que se te presenta es por error de sintaxis, te dejo el código corrigiendo los errores, adicional al error de la coma que ya te habían comentado.

el código que colocas es muy ambiguo y vago, sin embargo lo he modificado para añadir algunas rutinas que faltan (y modificando otras).

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional el cual espero te sirva para determinar donde esta el problema, Saludos!! ;))...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // invocar la rutina para crear elemento <select>
 td=crearCampoSelect("select");
 
 // invocar la rutina para insertar elemento <select> en <table>
 insertarcelda(td);
 
 // emular las rutinas ajax (solo para efectos de evaluación)
 echo="<option>option<option>";
 $("#rs").html(echo);
 return false;
 
 $.ajax({                   // <--- falta el paréntesis
  url: "consulta.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false
 }).done(function(echo){
  $("#rs").html(echo);      // <--- faltan las comillas
 });
});

function crearCampoSelect(nombre) {
 td = document.createElement('td');
 sel = document.createElement('select');
 sel.setAttribute('name',nombre);
 sel.setAttribute('id','rs'); 
 td.appendChild(sel);
 return td;
};

// rutina faltanta en el codigo que muestras
function insertarcelda(td) {
 document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0].append(td);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td></td></tr><table> <!-- codigo que falta en tu ejemplo -->
```

Comment: gracias por la observacion pero esos errores estan corregidos en el codigo, el problema no es en el ajax, eso funciona, mi problema es como lo integro en mi funcion para cuando la llame me cree el campo select y me muestre los resultados de la consulta